# ¿Existen distintas formas de definir métodos para un objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

Me surgió la duda, ya que lo he visto de dos formas distintas y la verdad es que dan el mismo resultado y no sé si tienen alguna diferencia en concreto. He visto estas dos formas de declarar un método en javascript:

1- Asignandole una function a una propiedad del objeto:

```
const persona = {
  nombre: "Leonardo",
  saludar: function() {
    console.log(`Hola! soy ${this.nombre}!!`)
  }
}


persona.saludar();
```

2- Definiendo el método directamente:

```
const persona = {
  nombre: "Agustín",
  saludar() {
  console.log(`Hola! soy ${this.nombre}!!`)
  }
}

persona.saludar();
```

Quería saber si primero estas distintas formas reciben un nombre en particular y segundo si existe una diferencia o es lo mismo.

Comment: No soy de tecnicismos pero la segunda forma viene de `ES6` y es por decirlo asi una forma `sugar sintactic` corta de declarar una funcion dentro de un objeto, esto es aplicable tambien por ejemplo  a las clases de `ES6`, de todas maneras recuerda siempre mirar la compatibilidad entre navegadores, ya que aquellos que no hagan uso de `ES6` o esten muy desactualizados simplemente no reconoceran la segunda forma.

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto a la primera pregunta (reciben nombre el particular), sí:

1. La función que le estás asignando recibe el nombre de "función anónima" (la función en sí no tiene nombre, de ahí el concepto de anónima), y puede dar lugar a errores si no controlas bien el contexto y las referencias de `this`. En lugar de ello, es más recomendable utilizar una *arrow function* (función flecha), que te ayuda en gran manera en ese aspecto.
2. La segunda forma, como bien ha introducido @riven, se trata de una de las novedades introducidas en ES6, y que permite acortar la definición de propiedades (sean métodos o no), y que no deja de ser una forma más simple de escribir funciones anónimas. Tienes más detalle si deseas en [este enlace](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties).

```js
const x = 1;

// Esta es la forma abreviada (sintaxis corta, syntactic sugar de ES6)
const obj = {
  x,
  f(a, b) {}
};

// Esta es la forma tradicional antes de ES6 o para browsers antiguos
const obj = {
  x: x,
  f: function(a, b) {}
};
```

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta (diferencia entre ambas formas), en el ejemplo propuesto no habría ninguna diferencia, por tratarse ambas de funciones anónimas asignadas a una propiedad de un objeto.

Espero haberte podido ayudar, y puedes utilizar los comentarios si algo no ha quedado claro.